# what is the difference between .js and .js?v=1.x

Tags: javascript

As far as i know, when we create a file .js, example: `layout.js`, we will load it like this:

```
<script src="../layout.js"></script>
```

It run ok.
But recently, I have been managed an project from other person. The file name is layout.js but they load like this:

```
<script src="../layout.js?v=1.1"></script>
```

I has been tested and removed "?v=1.1", both of them run ok.

Any help can explain detail what is the difference  between load: 
`<script src="../layout.js"></script>` and `<script src="../layout.js?v=1.1"></script>` ?

Comment: Appending ?v=X can be useful to force browsers to load new versions of the script instead of using a cached copy and potentially causing issues. Whenever you update the file, you can change the version number and it should ensure browsers load the file fresh. This can also be done for CSS files. There may be other uses I'm not aware of

Comment: @Jacin Tattersall: This mean, when we update file js or css. the client don't need to clear the cache of refresh the page of browse?

Comment: The client will still need to refresh the page or navigate to another page that uses the updated file, but they will not need to clear their cache.